# How can I add an external, third-party dependency to a perl6 project?

Tags: module, dependencies, raku, zef

Either I've missed it or there's no clear information about that topic.

1. Where should I look for **Perl 6** libraries? CPAN.org? Or only http://modules.perl6.org?
2. When I've chosen one, how can I add it to my Perl 6 project?
3. If I find it on GitHub, how can I add it to my Perl 6 project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please make sure to read @smonff's answer as well for responses to questions 2 and 3.

> 1. Where should I look for perl 6 libraries?

[modules.perl6.org](http://modules.perl6.org).

> 2. When I've chosen one, how can I add it to my perl 6 project?

Use [zef](https://docs.perl6.org/language/modules#index-entry-zef) to install it on your local system.

Read [the modules doc page](http://doc.perl6.org/language/modules) for directions on `use`ing a module in your project.

> 3. If I find it [somewhere], how can I add it to my perl 6 project?

If zef can see it (and zef will usually be able to see a module if its repo is listed at modules.perl6.org) then zef should be able to install it. If not, contact the author or ask about it on #perl6.

Answer (score 4):

As an answer to point 2) and 3) , you can take a look at [`6pm`](https://modules.perl6.org/search/?q=6pm). It's idea is to be *[NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/) for Perl6*. It could also be compared to Perl5's Carton. `6pm` works over `Zef`.

```
$ 6pm init

# Install dependencies to ./perl6-modules and add it to META6.json 
$ 6pm install Test::Meta --save

# Run a file using the local dependencies
$ 6pm exec-file test.p6

# Make your code always use 6pm by making it "use SixPM;"
$ perl6 test.p6
```

See the [full documentation](https://github.com/FCO/6pm) for more information.